# Instalacao geopy python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, geolocalização

Eu tenho python 2.7.12 instalado no meu computador (ubuntu 16.04) e instalei o geopy (1.11).
Porem quanto eu tento rodar meu script, aparece esse erro:

```
from geopy.distance import  lonlat, distance




ImportError: cannot import name lonlat
```

Alguem sabe me dizer o pq? E como eu faco p/ consertar?

Comment: Como instalou? Tem certeza que instalou corretamente, sem erros?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, eu usei: sudo pip install geopy. Apareceu essa msg: Requirement already satisfied: geopy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.11.0) bleach 2.1.3 has requirement tml5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre, but you'll have html5lib 0.9999999 which is incompatible.
Mas eu chequei p/ ver se estava instalado, e esta.

Comment: Tenta fazer o download e instalar manualmente. se você der um `from geopy.distance import lonlat` no console retorna o mesmo erro?

Comment: Como assim instalar manualmente? Desculpa, alem de python eu sou nova em linux tambem...E respondendo a sua pergunta, sim...fazendo isso no console, o erro eh o mesmo

Comment: Ao fazer `python --version` aparece a versão 2.7 mesmo?

Comment: Sim! Aparece Python 2.7.12

Comment: Você poderia usar `from geopy import distance` e depois usar a função `lonlat` chamando com `distance.lonlat()`. Se puder coloque o código completo na pergunta

Comment: [Testei agora](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/GeoPy-Distance) e o código está OK.
Tem que descobrir em que ambiente foi instalado o pacote. Como foi instalado com `sudo` é provável que o pacote não seja visível se o script não rodar com `sudo` também.

Comment: Como complementei na resposta, o problema está na versão do geopy. Precisa instalar a versão mais recente para usar o lonlat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o `distance` da seguinte forma:

Exemplo existente na [documentação do geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-geopy.distance)

```
from geopy import distance

newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
```

Para o lonlat pode fazer da mesma forma:

```
from geopy import distance

point = distance.lonlat(41.49008, -71.312796)
print(point)
```

**Editado** após marcado como aceita.

Após verificar os comentários e continuar apontando o erro foi verificado que a função `distance.lonlat` não existia na versão 1.11.0 do pacote `geopy`. Foi adicionada na [versão 1.14.0](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/releases/tag/1.14.0) e pode ser visto pelo comentário do release:

> **1.14.0**
>
> ADDED: geopy.distance.lonlat function for conveniently converting (x,
>   y, [z]) coordinate tuples to the Point instances, which use (y, x,
>   [z]).

Por esse motivo ocorre o erro no import. Nos comentários também foi indicado que o import usado na pergunta não está errado e pode ser usado desde que a versão certa do `geopy` esteja instalada.

O código que usa o `distance` funciona na versão 1.11.0 com o import feito da forma como está nessa resposta e não como está na pergunta porque o `distance` existe na versão 1.11.0, porém ele aponta para o método Vincenty. Na versão mais recente o `distance` passou a apontar para o métdodo Geodesic e incluiu a função `lonlat()`.

Comment: Mas não vejo porque isso iria interferir. Se `geopy.distance` possui `lonlat`, então deveria funcionar o `from .. import` da mesma maneira: https://repl.it/@acwoss/LivelyOrderlyLivecd, tanto que a própria documentação que citou faz desta maneira.

Comment: O código dela é funcional ([Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/GeoPy-Distance)) o problema é com a instalação do pacote.

Comment: Fazendo dessa maneira: point = distance.lonlat(41.49008, -71.312796), tambem da errado...O erro que aparece eh: AttributeError: type object 'vincenty' has no attribute 'lonlat'. Eu tambem acho que o problema deve estar na instalacao, eu so nao sei como faco p/ arrumar...como eu disse antes, sou nova no linux

Comment: A resposta não diz que a outra forma de usar o `import` está errada. Eu coloquei o "tente" porque eu testei com a versão 1.16.0 (última) e depois que funcionou percebi que o problema dela é porque ela está usando a versão 1.11.0. Vou editar a resposta.